# Advice on How to Build my Own StringBuilder class in Java?

Tags: java, string

This is a homework problem, so I'm not looking for direct answers, but I am quite lost as to where to even begin with this problem. I am tasked with creating my own implementation of the StringBuilder class called MyStringBuilder. I am given several methods that I must work with to create this class.

I have been reading about the StringBuilder class to try to figure out how to implement this, but I feel just as lost as I did at the beginning. These are the methods we have been provided:

```
public class MyStringBuilder {

   public MyStringBuilder(String s) {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder(char[] chars) {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder append(MyStringBuilder s) {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder append(int i) {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder insert(int offset, MyStringBuilder s) {

   }

   public int length() {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder reverse() {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder toLowerCase() {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder toUpperCase() {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder substring(int begin, int end) {

   }

   public MyStringBuilder substring(int begin) {

   }

   public String toString() {

   }
}
```

Edit 1: I should also mention that we aren't allowed to use any already available Java methods. All of the functionality of each method has to be written by me, which is making this much harder!

Comment: Think about what a `StringBuilder` actually *is*--from a conceptual level it's just a way of taking a string and tacking on other different strings. For example, it could be an array of characters. (Noting that you can just look at the source as well.)

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you! I tried reading the source code a bit, but honestly it still just isn't very clear to me, which is unfortunate. I'm struggling with figuring out how to even start.

Comment: Well, the first thing you should probably do is to create a new `char`-array to store the contents of your `StringBuilder`. Then, implement the methods that manipulate that array. For example, the `toUpperCase` method could iterate over all elements of the array and replace them with their upper-case representation, the `length` method would simply return `array.length`, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`StringBuilder` is essentially an growing list of characters. `StringBuilder` implementation in JDK has two fields:

```
/**
 * The value is used for character storage.
 */
char[] value;

/**
 * The count is the number of characters used.
 */
int count;
```

The size of `value` array is always no less than `count`. The point here is that StringBuilder reserves some empty space in its internal array to improve performance.

Let's look at implementation of `append(char c)` method:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder append(char c) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(count + 1);  // <----
    value[count++] = c;
    return this;
}
```

If the `value` array is big enough, we can just put that character in it.

Otherwise, we have to create a bigger array (in JDK implementation, the size doubles), and copy the old data over to it. So now the new character will fit. That's what `ensureCapacityInternal` does.